# Direct product of abelian group of $4$

Tags: group-theory

[image]

$1)$ Let's consider the first direct product, namely $\{e,a\}\times \{e,b\}=\{(e,e),(e,b),(e,e),(a,b)\}$. However as we see the author wrote that $G=\{e,a\}\times \{e,b\}$. But the elements of  $G$ and direct product $\{e,a\}\times \{e,b\}$ have distinct nature, so we cannot say that they are equal. Can anyone explain this subtle moment, please?

$2)$ I have the same question to the second direct product, namely $\{e,ab\}\times \{e,b\}=\{(e,e),(e,b),(ab,e),(ab,b)\}$.  Why $G$ is equal to that direct product?

Comment: This is the difference between the internal direct product and the external direct product, which are isomorphic, but not equal.

Comment: @DerekHolt, Dear Derek, let me ask you the following question. In Herstein's book I have encountered the notions of external direct product and internal direct product. Also I've worked the theorem which states that these groups are isomorphic. In other words, they are "similar" structures since isomorphism preserve structure of group. And Herstein adds that "we could abolish the prefix external and internal in the phrases external direct product, internal direct product - after all these would be the same group up to isomorphism-and just talk about the direct product"

Comment: @DerekHolt, However i cannot understand the notion of direct product quite properly. Let's consider the following phrase "Let $G$ be a group such that $G=A_1\times A_2\times \dots \times A_k$". How to understand that? What means here these symbols, namely "$\times$"? If it means direct product, then what does mean "direct product" here? I would be very grateful if you can help me with this question. Trying to understand this few days but no results.

Comment: This could mean either the external direct product, which is the set of $k$-tuples $(a_1,\ldots,a_k)$ with $a_i \in A_i$, and with the group operation component-wise. Or it could mean that $G$ is the internal direct product of its subgroups $A_i$. Herstein has said that he does not plan to distinguish between these two meanings, even though they are not identical.

Comment: @DerekHolt, Thanks a lot for answer! So in order to check that $G$ is direct product of $A_1, \dots, A_k$ i.e. $G=A_1\times \dots \times A_k$ we need to check out one of these definitions, right? Either external direct product or internal direct product. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, but usually if you are given $G$ then you would look for suitable subgroups in order check that it was an internal direct product. The external direct product is a group that you construct from given subgroups.

Answer (score 1):

Abstractly, the direct product of groups $A_i$. $i\in I$, is a group $P$ together(!) with homomorphisms $\pi_i\colon P\to A_i$, $i\in I$, such that for every group $X$ and family of homomorphisms $f_i\colon X\to A_i$, $i\in I$, there exists one and only one homomorphism $h\colon X\to P$ such that $\pi_i\circ h=f_i$ for all $i\in I$. 
In this abstract sense, the direct product is only defined up to canonical isomorphism, hence the use of equality instead of just isomorphism is hard to justify.

The co-product (or direct sum) is defined analogously, with all arrows reversed. By the very definitions, there is always a canonical homomorphism from "the" direct sum to "the" direct product. In the case of finite $I$, it turns out that this is an isomorphism, i.e., in that situation we need not distinguish between the two concepts.

That being said, in the current scenario, it seems that the author discusses *internal* direct products (or rather - nitpickingly - sums). If $G$ is a group and $A,B$ are subgroups of $G$ and it happens to be the case that $G$ together with the inclusion homomorphisms is a direct sum, we say that $G$ *is* the (inner) direct product of $A$ and $B$, or $G=A\times B$ (note the use of $=$ instead of $\cong$). This is stronger than saying that $G\cong A\times B$ becauas the latter can happen even if $A$ and $B$ do not commute as subgroups of $G$.

This is what is meant in the statements that $G=A\times B$ and $G=C\times B$.

Comment: Thanks for post but your definition of direct product is quite difficult and completely dictinct from mine (Herstein's book). Unfortunately, I was not able to digest your answer :(